# Jasper Report Variable printing zero value

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on a jasper report in which I am using following SQL query:

```
select SOURCE, count(*) as total
from CASE_UPLOADS
where UPLOAD_DT >= '20150601'
and UPLOAD_DT <= '20150630'
group by SOURCE
order by SOURCE
```

and the result is:

```
SOURCE,TOTAL
"New Application";15
"Periodic Report";16
"RD/RC";25
```

I have created variable like:

```
<variable name="PR" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{source} == 'Periodic_Report') ? $F{total} : 0]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

This variable is printing zero value each time.

If I change conditional clause as follow:

```
<variable name="PR" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{source} == 'Periodic Report') ? 0 : $F{total}]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>
```

Then its printing SUM 56 of TOTAL column.

Field declaration:

```
<field name="source" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="total" class="java.lang.Long"/>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Periodic_Report - There is underscore in the expression $F{source} == 'Periodic_Report'), where as the value is "Periodic Report"

Comment: @Arasu That was by mistake. Without '_' also its giving same result

Comment: try this $F{source}.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Periodic Report")

Comment: what is the value for $F{source} when you print on the report? check if it is surrounded with quotes.

Comment: If I print $F{source} and $V{PR} in detail band next to each other then its printing like: New Application 0,Periodic Report 0,RD/RC 0

Comment: can you please show me the field declaration part.

Comment: @Arasu added into the description

Comment: Jasper Reports is case-sensitive. create field like "<field name="SOURCE" class="java.lang.String"/>" and try

Comment: Try to use  ($F{source}.equals("Periodic Report")) ? $F{total} : 0

Comment: Its lower case only. In my description i made it capital. So at both places its same

Comment: oops! You said equalsIgnoreCase didn't work... sorry